# Syntax error... can't find it

Tags: php, sql, syntax, pdo, syntax-error

There is an error in the SQL syntax below, supposedly on the last line (closing: "));") according to the error thrown. I can't see what's wrong. Anyone here spot it?

No other errors thrown. Just the syntax error. However, it states "...the right syntax to use near ''..." but references line 244 which is the closing of execute.

```
$save = $database->prepare('INSERT INTO checklists VALUES(:id, :name, :user, :agent, :status, :date_created, :date_submitted, :last_updated, :technique, :machine, :ink, :finish, :item, :thickness, :rolls, :sheets, :deformation, :deformation_details, :surface, :surface_details, :process, :process_details, :quality, :quality_details, :drying, :drying_details, :finishing, :finishing_details, :reason, :how, :uid');
$save->execute(array(
    ':id' => ' ',
    ':name' => $name,
    ':user' => $printer,
    ':agent' => $agent,
    ':status' => '0',
    ':date_created' => $stamp,
    ':date_submitted' => $sub,
    ':last_updated' => $stamp,
    ':technique' => '',
    ':machine' => '',
    ':ink' => '',
    ':finish' => '',
    ':item' => '',
    ':thickness' => '',
    ':rolls' => '',
    ':sheets' => '',
    ':deformation' => '',
    ':deformation_details' => '',
    ':surface' => '',
    ':surface_details' => '',
    ':process' => '',
    ':process_details' => '',
    ':quality' => '',
    ':quality_details' => '',
    ':drying' => '',
    ':drying_details' => '',
    ':finishing' => '',
    ':finishing_details' => '',
    ':reason' => '',
    ':how' => '',
    ':uid' => $uid
));
```

Comment: Check the end of first line:  `:uid');` there should be one additional brace: `:uid)');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `)` missing ad and of your statement:

```
... :reason, :how, :uid)');
```

Comment: Man haha of course... I was focusing entirely on the line the error referenced and didn't bother to check the actual query. Thanks! Accepting as answer in 10 min.